NextJs deployed on Elastic Beanstalk error in production
I have a NextJs (v14.1.0) application deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The project is deployed using AWS Codebuild (buildspec.yml). It was working perfectly then I started getting a 500 internal error response in Chrome dev console. This happened without making any changes to the application or environment. This is only happening for the production build.
In the browser, When I navigate to the URL where the application is deployed, I get the following:
Screenshot of chrome developer console logs
On the server, the following errors show up in the web.stdout.log log file.
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: TypeError: C is not a function
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at rW (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:10505)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9396
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async Promise.all (index 0)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async rW (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9204)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9396
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async Promise.all (index 0)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async rW (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9204) {
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:  digest: '4228333707'
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: }
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: TypeError: C is not a function
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at rW (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:10505)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9396
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async Promise.all (index 0)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async rW (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9204)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9396
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async Promise.all (index 0)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at async rW (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:9204) {
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:  digest: '4228333707'
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: }
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: TypeError: s is not a function
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:13:2748
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at eh (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:134795)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at e (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:137680)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at ek (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:138154)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at Array.toJSON (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:135764)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at stringify (<anonymous>)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at eR (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142228)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at eE (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142707)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:135484)
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17) {
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:  digest: '2260024538'
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: }
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: [Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:  digest: '2260024538'
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: }
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: â¨¯ [Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]:  digest: '2260024538'
Apr 12 14:57:06 web[27070]: }

The interesting thing is that I have some API routes which return data without any errors if I navigate to them in the broswer but if I go to a route/page in the app directory, it fails.
Example

https://example.com/api/health <--- works (API Route)
https://example.com/login <--- doesnt work (Login Page)

Version

nextjs: 14.1.0
react / react-dom: 18.2.0
node: 18.18.2
npm: 9.8.1

To resolve this I attempted to:

Download the problematic build from codebuild and attempted to run it using the npm run start command locally and got the same error.
Revert to an older version of the application and the same errors happen.
Create the production build locally but I got NO errors or issues (issuse seems to be only happening on the production build).
I ensure the version is on my local machine, codebuild and the ElasticBeanstalk environment are the same.

This is my buildspec.yml used to build the project in production
version: 0.2

cache:
  paths:
    - 'node_modules/**/*' # Cache `node_modules` for faster `yarn` or `npm i`
    - '.next/cache/**/*' # Cache Next.js for faster application rebuilds

phases:
  install:
    on-failure: ABORT 
    # runtime-versions:
    #   nodejs: 18.18.x
    commands:
      # Installing the same version on the ElasticBeanStalk instance  
      - n 18.18.2
      - node --version
      - npm --version
      - npm install
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - node --version
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      # Copying only the files we need to the dist folder because 
      # that is used as our base directory for the artifact
      - mkdir dist/
      - cp -r .next dist/
      - cp -r .ebextensions dist/
      - cp package.json Procfile .env.production dist/

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: dist


So it seems the AWS Elastic Beanstalk updated the node version or some other dependencies in their environment and because I was not pushing my local package-lock.json to the server, there were a few mismatches with some dependencies and dependencies of other dependencies.
